# How to filter data based on drop down menu value?

Tags: angularjs

*Note: AngularJS version 1.2.28*

I am a newbie to AngularJS and trying to hide elements based on the value chosen in a drop down menu. If the drop down option of "Black" is selected, the data table should only show elements with a division color of "Black". If the drop down option of "Yellow" is selected, the data table should only show elements with a division color of "Yellow".

**How would I go about filtering data and hide the items that do not contain the value selected in the drop down menu?**

Here's my sample data (**I left out the app and controller directive for brevity**):

```
[{ lastName: 'Doe', firstName: 'John', division: 'Blue'}, 
{ lastName: 'Smith', firstName: 'Jane', division: 'Yellow' }]
```

Drop Down HTML:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="division">Black</option>
    <option value="division">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Table View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    ...snip ...
    </thead>
</table>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: orderProp">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
        $scope.orderProp = 'lastName';
    });
});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Don't you mean **hide the item that contains the selected value?** instead of **hide the items that do not contain the selected value** other wise your list will only contain 1 value, which is the selected value. So if `Yellow` is selected, what do want your output list in `ng-repeat` to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you should add default filter like you added orderBy (which is also some kind of filter):

```
<table>
    <thead>
    ...snip ...
    </thead>
</table>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: orderProp | orderBy: orderProp">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[HERE](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/filter/filter) you can find more about filter function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {division: orderProp}">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and why do you need `$scope.orderProp = 'lastName';` in controller? Remove it if not really needed